# Google Chrome: Zero width table cells use up space

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have a table with three `<td />`. Two of them have `width` attributes and styles of `0px`.
The middle `<td />` has no explicit `width` set.

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5H6eS/)

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="0" height="10" bgcolor="" style="background-color:#00ffff;height:10px;width:0px;"></td>
            <td height="10" bgcolor="" style="background-color:#000;height:10px;"></td>
            <td width="0" height="10" bgcolor="" style="background-color:#ff00ff;height:10px;width:0px;"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would expect that this middle `<td />` would take up the entire space (and this is what happens in Firefox and IE)

However, in Google Chrome, the three `<td />` all take up the same space.

**1. Why is this?

 2. Is this a bug in Chrome?

 3. Is there an easy fix?**

Answer (score 5):

It looks like Firefox and IE have the default property "table-layout:fixed" for tables. But Chrome doesn't have this as a default property. So we need to force this in chrome like below.

```
 table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px; 
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
table-layout:fixed;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/5H6eS/5/)

Comment: In latest FF I can see a black color only. while in chrome as stated in code I can see all 3 color as specified. any comments?

Comment: You are right kheema. OP want to fix the chrome issue.

Comment: I see same behavior now in chrome as well. I were not aware about this chrome bug.

Comment: Browsers do not have `table-layout:fixed` as the default.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have always been inconsistent in allocating column widths in tables when some widths are set but they do not unambiguously define all the widths.

In this case, the table has a width of 100% and two of the columns a width of 0. However, the `width` setting for a table cell sets just the *minimum* width, and browsers may allocate wider cells (columns) to satisfy a width setting for the entire table.

Here the solution is simple: just add `width: 100%` to the style settings of the middle cell.